# How to clean rxjs cache with standard method

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have a service which is caching data from the server. But I need clean cache every 10 seconds after the last call of `getView()`.

```
import {shareReplay} from 'rxjs/operators';


cache$: Observable<any>;
getView() {
  if (!this.organizationViewCache$) {
    this.cache$ = this.baseApiDependenciesService.http.post(
      `my-api`, {}, this.getHeaders()
    ).pipe(
      shareReplay(1),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
  return this.organizationViewCache$;
}
```

Perhaps here's good `const timer$ = timer(0, 10000);` from `{timer} from 'rxjs/observable/timer';` but I can't figure out how to:

1. Connect `timer.pipe()` and `shareReplay(1)`, bacause `shareReplay(1)` already inside `http.post.pipe`?
2. Clean cache **not** every 10 seconds but 10 seconds after the last call of `getView()` method. (If this possible, but not strong required)

**UPDATE**

I find the solution which does similar behavior but I need do the same but with `RX/JS` tools:

```
getView() {
  if (!this.organizationViewCache$) {
    this.cache$ = this.baseApiDependenciesService.http.post(
      `my-api`, {}, this.getHeaders()
    ).pipe(
      shareReplay(1),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.cache$ = null;
    }, 10000)
  }
  return this.organizationViewCache$;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by clean rxjs cache? I think you can use something like pipe( switchMap(timer$)...)

Comment: @ABOS I mean drop `cache$` value for `if (!this.organizationViewCache$)` return `true` after 10 seconds the last call.

Comment: @ABOS can you write more detail example of you're the suggestion?

Comment: I do not fully understand what you are trying to do, so just some rough idea. I added answer below, for easiness to read

Answer (score 1):

Could be something like ?

```
.pipe(
   switchMap(timer$),
   tap(()=>cached$=null)
)
```

So the idea is that if you call service again, the inner time$ will be cancelled, and a new one will be created starting from scratch again. But I am not sure if that is the actual behavior you want.

Comment: do you mean `use `shitchMap` and `tap` after `catchError` something like   `.pipe(           shareReplay(1),
          catchError(this.handleError)
   switchMap(timer$),
   tap(()=>cached$=null)
)`

Comment: timer$ should not cause error in this case, so I would just keep catchError in http call

Comment: I'm confused would you please rewrite your an example of how to connect this solution with my context of http request. I can't figure out how to unite pipe() from my HTTP request and pipe from you're the solution. How organized that in one chain.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean, you want call some function after you getting called **getView()** each  10 second.

you could use **Interval** from rxjs, see about [documentation](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/interval)

```
interval(10000).pipe( 
  tap(x => this.cache$ = null)
).subscribe();
```

the Interval will execute, this.cache$ to be null, each 10 second.